# jvm minor version vs compiler minor version

Tags: java, jvm

Will JVM throw exception when it runs classes compiled with a JDK that has same major version but higher minor version compared to JVM  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDK version does not really matter, the [class file format version](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/source_target_class_file_version) does. So far, the minor version of the class file format hasn't been used, and changes in the major version have always corresponded with major JDK release (counting 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 1.4 as major releases).

Additionally, the `-target` option of `javac` can be used to produce class files compatible with older runtimes.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  It is the class file format version.

I tried to look for authoritative reference from Sun which would list what JDK results in what class version. I could only find this information from various blogs.

major  minor Java platform version 
45       3           1.0
45       3           1.1
46       0           1.2
47       0           1.3
48       0           1.4
49       0           1.5
50       0           1.6

Answer (score 2):

No, the JVM will only complain if you try to run code that has been compiled for a higher major version of the language. For example you can run code compiled with JDK1.4 on a 1.6 VM.