# Problems when deploying a War compiled with a 1.6.0.24 to a 1.6.0.22

Tags: java, tomcat, compilation, version, war

Good Day.

After searching at stack, I have found many similar questions like:

[In what cases legacy Java code would not compile on newer versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994992/in-what-cases-legacy-java-code-would-not-compile-on-newer-versions)

[jvm minor version vs compiler minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699354/jvm-minor-version-vs-compiler-minor-version)

[Unsupported major.minor version 49.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525960/unsupported-major-minor-version-49-0)

But, as I understand, they speak about problems with differents Mayor version (1.5 vs 1.6) and similar.

**I think my problem is different:**
The developers send us a war compiled with the 1.6.0.24, but our tomcat runs on the 1.6.0.22 JVM...

Will it run without problems? ¿Is the recommended approach or must i told then to recomplie with older version Are similar minor version "enough" close each other?

We tried to deploy it and the Tomcat started, but 24 hours later it hanged. The server was running for 8 months without problem... so I'm a bit lost and will thank any advice.

Thanks

Comment: you should probably scan the logs to see why it actually hung?

Comment: It should run without any problem.

Comment: @asgs Checked. No one telling anything useful. @Yasin I was expecting so. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no class file format change between those versions (or any other minor updates). You can safely run code compiled with Java 6 Update 24 on Java 6 Update 22.

I suspect your real problem is related to some other change.

Comment: Thanks Joaquim. Your reputation is big enough to belive you.